# How to create a page based WatchKit app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pagination, watchkit

I'm trying to create a **page based WatchKit app**. When the app loads I want a page with an image and a button in a paginated view and swiping should switch between an array of images.

[image: Home View]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yn3tstngx8h94xo/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20-%20Apple%20Watch%2009-Mar-2015%203.28.01%20am.png?dl=0

I tried `WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(["home", "home", "home", "home", "home"], contexts: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])` where `home` is the identifier of the InterfaceController. I'm calling this method from another InterfaceController which is the initial interface controller. I get the page based views but the initial view is blank.

```
    import WatchKit
    import Foundation

    class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

        override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
            super.awakeWithContext(context)

            WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(["home", "home", "home", "home", "home"], contexts: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])
        }

        override func willActivate() {
            // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
            super.willActivate()
        }

        override func didDeactivate() {
            // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
            super.didDeactivate()
        }
    }
```

1. Am i doing it right using the `reloadRootControllersWithNames` method to create a page based application?

   - Where should I call this method?
   - Is there an entry point file like the `AppDelegate` for WatchKit other than the arrow in the storyboard?
   - Can I configure the paginated views in the storyboard itself without writing separate code?
2. Right now my entire view is paginated. I just want the images to change, I don't want the button to move. How can I accomplish this?
   http://www.apple.com/watch/films/#film-fitness Please check this video. I want the pagination they show here at 02:17.
3. Last thing is the animations they do. The animations they show for the texts and the exercise rings. I'd be really thankful if anyone can give me an idea on how to do such animations. :)

Comment: You shouldn't be coding in both objective c and swift, choose one of those tags :)

Comment: @penne12 I just wanted more people to see my question and I thought an objective-c tag would help ;)
My Parent app is written in Objective-C. Should I prefer Objective-C or Swift for the WatchKit extensions?

Comment: Whatever you like best :) I think Swift, but you should explore your options :)

Answer (score 3):

Answering question 1 only:

I created a page-based app using almost exactly the technique you used here, except that I called WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames()
from the willActivate() function, not the awakeWithContext() function. Not sure if this is important.

I am assuming that "home" is the identifier for a different WKInterfaceController? I do not think it will work correctly if you try to use the starting interface controller as the paged interface controller. So that could be the source of your problem.

However this method of specifying pages programmatically is only needed if you have a variable number of pages. If you know your page layout at build time, you can lay them all out in your storyboard, then Control-drag from one too the other, choosing the "Next page" relationship.

If you do it using the storyboard, you can have the starting interface controller as the first of the pages, and then subsequent interface controllers can use the same class if you want them to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). I have actually implemented it inside the "awakeWithContext" method. I just wanted to reuse the view because the layout is same for all the paginated views and just the data changes. I think I'm through with the UI and animations now. But the data transfer between the Watch and iPhone is what I need to implement now. I have been checking Apple's Lister app. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html
Hopefully I'll get through this soon. Please share your ideas on how to efficiently communicate between Watch and iPhone.

Comment: Check out this post: http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/3/11/one-weird-trick-to-fix-openparentapplicationreply

Answer (score 0):

The answers to #2 and #3 are easy: you can't, at least not in the current version of WatchKit.

Comment: The exercise rings can be done using image animations. Not sure if the text animation is possible.

Comment: You can see a sample implementation of the animation rings here in this sample code from apple 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html